# What does Xcode 11.3.1's scene kit editor "Velocity Field" (SKVelocityFieldNode) do?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I'm trying to add some velocity to an object in Xcode's scene editor.  I looked in the Objects Library and saw "Velocity Field" which creates what it calls SKVelocityFieldNode.  There's no documentation at all on SKVelocityFieldNode?  Google can't find anything.  Anyone know whether this can be used to apply a velocity to an SKNode?

Answer (score 1):

It’s what you get when you create a velocity field.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skfieldnode/1519778-velocityfield